# Image elements will not scale to screen size in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a single page site that is designed for information purposes only once an element is clicked.

I almost have things done, but I have found that the div element only scales in Safari. It does not work in Firefox or Chrome?

Here is a link to the site - [Click Me](http://www.bbk.ac.uk/~dmcken03/HS2DM/index.html)

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. 
Point to note - the background image is fine. Its just the element sitting on top that is posing the problem right now.

Comment: Firefox will never react on -webkit-transform, look for CSS vendor prefixes. Can't see any difference between safari and chrome, could you describe what exactly you want. Should the position of the pointer  always be the same (relative to background)?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If you click my link and then change the screen size, you will see that the background image scales fine, but the div element will remain at its fixed position and does not scale uniformly. However, if you do the above in Safari, you will see the element scale appropriately.

Comment: Sorry @PrimalScientist Safari and Chrome behave the same for me, the pointer image is scaling when you resize, but the position changes.

Comment: Ahh yes, Chrome seems fine now. Yes, thats the next problem I am looking at. Position Absolute? I just need to concentrate on getting it to scale in Firefox first.

Comment: Also, take a look at this - works great - but again, not in Firefox...
http://jsfiddle.net/dg3kj/39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle your scale problem: jQuery >= 1.8 automaticly adds vendor prefixes. So instead of:

```
 $('#outer').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
```

You could write:

```
 $('#outer').css({'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
```

this should fix your FireFox problem. In case you work with an older Version of jQuery, have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/cballou/4007063). It is plugin for adding these vendor prefixes. The following code example is from the plugin CSSHooks.

```
(function($) {
  if ( !$.cssHooks ) {
    throw("jQuery 1.4.3+ is needed for this plugin to work");
    return;
  }

  function styleSupport( prop ) {
    var vendorProp, supportedProp,
        capProp = prop.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + prop.slice(1),
        prefixes = [ "Moz", "Webkit", "O", "ms" ],
        div = document.createElement( "div" );

    if ( prop in div.style ) {
      supportedProp = prop;
    } else {
      for ( var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++ ) {
        vendorProp = prefixes[i] + capProp;
        if ( vendorProp in div.style ) {
          supportedProp = vendorProp;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    div = null;
    $.support[ prop ] = supportedProp
    return supportedProp;
  }

  // check for style support of your property 
  // TODO by user: swap out myCssPropName for css property
  var myCssPropName = styleSupport("myCssPropName");

  // set cssHooks only for browsers that
  // support a vendor-prefixed border radius
  if (myCssPropName && myCssPropName !== 'myCssPropName') {
    $.cssHooks["myCssPropName"] = {
      get: function(elem, computed, extra) {
        // handle getting the CSS property
        return $.css(elem, myCssPropName);
      },
      set: function(elem, value) {
        // handle setting the CSS value
        elem.style[myCssPropName] = value;
      }
    };
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Anyway, with that you are not done, the position problem will still exists.

**Update**

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dg3kj/40/) - took your example from above, and corrected the css line. Looks correct in FF, Safari and Chrome.